# How to print a Git LFS file's old version to stdout (git show / git cat-file for LFS)?

Tags: git, git-lfs

Another title for this question could be 'How to checkout multiple versions of a Git-LFS managed file?'

I would like to inspect several versions of a file stored in Git-LFS. I would therefore like to several versions of this file side-by-side in my working directory. Something like this is what I have in mind:

```
git show v1:./myfile.ipynb > myfile-v1.ipynb
git show v2:./myfile.ipynb > myfile-v2.ipynb
```

This does not work as desired: the file is managed by Git-LFS, so to `git  show` its contents at each version looks like

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:62aafe00ec8b61a37dd729e7d3a723382...
size 20439
```

I am interested in the file's 'true', Git-LFS-managed contents, rather than the pointer file that LFS stores in Git's own tree.

How can I create untracked, custom-named files that each contain a specific version of a file tracked by Git-LFS? This does not need to be a single command, I am resigned to Git needing multi-step scripts for single-concept actions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Piping an lfs pointer into `git lfs smudge` will yield you what you want. For example:

```
git cat-file blob <blob-sha> | git lfs smudge
```

Or if you have a commit-ish (a commit hash, branch name, just `HEAD`, etc.) and a file name:

```
git cat-file blob <commit-ish>:path/to/my-large-file.name | git lfs smudge
```

You could redirect the output into a file.

Comment: @Koterpillar the `:<file>` part is only necessary if the sha is the sha of a tree-ish. If it's a sha of a blob itself, then that's all there is.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: [@Markonius' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54548429/288201) is the proper way to do it.

Here is a script that does this based on experimenting with an LFS repository. I didn't look at the LFS protocol in details, so there might be quirks unaccounted for, but it worked for my simple case.

[git-lfs-cat-file](https://github.com/koterpillar/desktop/blob/02c01fee06944ab3e211da253c201e1dc40c0595/bin/git-lfs-cat-file)

The relevant details are:

- LFS files are stored in the index with the following structure:

  ```
  version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
  oid sha256:abcdeffffffffffffff
  size nnnnnnnn
  ```
- Actual LFS object will then be under `.git/lfs/objects/ab/cd/abcdeffffffffffffff`.

Answer (score 0):

When last I was working with LFS, there were conversations on the project page about better integration - such as by writing diff and/or merge tools that could be plugged in via `.gitattributes`.  These didn't seem to be considered high priority, since the main intended use case of LFS is to protect large *binary* files (but certainly I've come across multiple cases where either I had a large text file, or the only reasonable way to set up LFS tracking rules cast a wide enough net to catch some smaller text files).  I'm not sure if there's been any progress on those tools, as I haven't looked at the project page in a while.

Absent those things, there's not a particularly "slick" way to do what you're asking.  You can set up two work trees and check out different versions.  You can check out one version, rename it, and then check out the other.

Comment: Printing binary files to stdout is indeed unattractive. That doesn't matter to me because I intend to redirect that stdout into a file. `git show`, too, streams both text and binary files to stdout and leaves redirection up to the user. (Also, Jupyter notebooks contain base64-encoded images and can get quite large.) Thank you for advising on those Git-LFS discussions, and thank you for your answer; the checkout-and-rename dance looks like it will suit my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this to get an LFS file from last commit, but you can supply your commit hash to get a copy from a different commit:

```
@echo off
set FILE= your repo file path here
set OUTPUT= your local output file here
set ORIGIN=origin master
set TEMP_FILE=_result.tmp

# Fetch to make sure we have history but don't merge since we don't want to mess with local repo
git fetch %ORIGIN% --quiet

# get last commit hash and date into variables
git log -n 1 %ORIGIN% --no-merges --pretty=format:%%H > %TEMP_FILE%
set /p COMMIT= < %TEMP_FILE%
git log -n 1 %ORIGIN% --no-merges --date=iso-strict-local --pretty=format:%%cI > %TEMP_FILE%
set /p DATE= < %TEMP_FILE%

# get blob id for the file on specific commit
git ls-tree --full-name --full-tree %COMMIT% -r "%FILE%" > %TEMP_FILE%
set /p LINE= < %TEMP_FILE%
set "BLOB=%LINE:~12,40%"

# check if file is under LFS
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command "git ls-files ':(attr:filter=lfs)' | select-string '^%FILE%'" > %TEMP_FILE%
set /p LFS= < %TEMP_FILE%

# use git cat-file to extract the file bytes from the blob to an output file
if "%LFS%" == "" (
    git cat-file blob "%BLOB%" > "%OUTPUT%"
    set "LFS="
) else (
    git cat-file blob "%BLOB%" | git lfs smudge > "%OUTPUT%"
    set "LFS=(LFS) "
)

# Set commit date as creation date of the output file
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Item '%OUTPUT%').CreationTime=('%DATE%')"

# read file size in KB
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command "[math]::Round((Get-Item '%OUTPUT%').Length/1KB,2)" > %TEMP_FILE%
set /p BYTES= < %TEMP_FILE%
del %TEMP_FILE%

# done, display a user friendly message
echo Extracted [%FILE%] from commit [%COMMIT%], commit date [%DATE%] to [%OUTPUT%] , %LFS%%BYTES% KB
```