# Get old revision of a git-lfs file

Tags: git, git-lfs

Kinda like how I can do `git cat-file blob <object-hash>` and get the file's raw data, I would like to get an old revision of a file tracked by LFS, so that I can save it somewhere. How would I do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a Git LFS file's old version to stdout (git show / git cat-file for LFS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50760795/how-to-print-a-git-lfs-files-old-version-to-stdout-git-show-git-cat-file-for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:
`git cat-file blob <sha> | git lfs smudge`

Comment: There's no such git-lfs 'cat-file' command (anymore).

Comment: @CharlesLanglois oops, it was supposed to be `git cat-file`, thanks for mentioning it